# SSRS If Column X value = "X" then display corresponding column Y value

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2008 and have a dataset that looks like this: (simplified)

```
RESULTGUID    Question    ANSWER 
1234          How Old     15
1234          How New     13
1234          How Big     700
1234          How Small   100
etc etc
```

I'm looking for an IIF statement like:

```
=iif(fields!Question.value = "How Old",Fields!Answer.value,"N/A")
```

However, this doesn't work apart from the first row, so if first(fields!  etc then works fine, but not for the rows lower down the data-set.

Can anyone offer a solution to this please ?

Comment: is that the expression you're using?   What is output on subsequent rows?

Comment: Hi. the subsequent rows just return a N/A.  However, I have solved this using a lookup to itself.  So =lookup("How Old",Fields!Question.value,Fields!Answer.value,"This Dataset")

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it all in SSRS it could be one big nested Iif statement:

```
=Iif(fields!Question.value = "How Old",Fields!Answer.value,Iif(fields!Question.value = "How New",Fields!Answer.value,
Iif(fields!Question.value = "How Big",Fields!Answer.value,Iif(fields!Question.value = "How Small",Fields!Answer.value,"N/A"))))
```

or you could do a SWITCH statement:

```
=SWITCH(
    fields!Question.value = "How Old", Fields!Answer.value
    fields!Question.value = "How New", Fields!Answer.value
    fields!Question.value = "How Big", Fields!Answer.value
    fields!Question.value = "How Small", Fields!Answer.value
    )
```

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestions SQLHound, I managed to solve it using a lookup to itself. So =lookup("How Old",Fields!Question.value,Fields!Answer.value,"This Dataset").  Thanks again.